# ActiveX component can not create object

Tags: com, activex

We changed the function name “aaa” into bbb in vbexample.dll, and registered into VB application. After registering it is getting executed in my local PC. After that when I generated a build of that VB application and tested it in another PC, it is not working.  The Message I get is: "ActiveX component can not create object".

Answer (score 0):

How is the COM object being instantiated on the other PC?  If you rebuild the app on one PC and then move it to another PC afterward, it's likely that VB has built it with another IID, and the other computer doesn't recognize it.